# Oracle SQL Developer: Sum rows based on value from another column

Tags: oracle

```
Trans. ID        QTY      TOOL   Date
    1            20        A2    2015
    2            20        A2    2016
    3            20        A2    2016
    4            20        A3    2015
    5            20        A3    2016
    6            20        A3    2016
    7            20        C     2016
    8            20        C     2016
    9            20        C     2016
    10           20        C     2016
```

To Return
--Interested in 2016 only

```
Tool     Total
A2         40
A3         40
```

Im not interested in the individual IDS. Just more interested totals. 
Please notw Im also interested in grabbing data with tools specifically starting with the letter A since the actual table has a bunch of tools.

Im having a hard time figuring out how to put the WHERE statement and other things. I read in another thread to use distincts as well.

```
select Tool, sum(QTY)
from 
  (select distinct Tool, ID, QTY from "table")
where Tool like 'A%'
AND Date like '2016%'
group by PROCESS_EQP_ID
```

Comment: What is `ID`, what is `PROCESS_EQP_ID`, why do you have a nested select at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the distinct in your subquery, you are going to knock out one of the rows with ids 2 and 3. However, from your expected output, you want both to be summed.

Also, what datatype is the date column? If it's DATE or TIMESTAMP, then I think this is what you're after:

```
select tool, sum(qty)
from   "table"
where  tool like 'A%'
and    to_char(dt, 'yyyy') = '2016' -- note that I've renamed the date column as `date` is a reserved word in Oracle.
group by tool;
```